# cURL command to PHP code returns error

Tags: php, json, rest, api, curl

I am trying to post data to create a customer using Rotessa API. I am using curl command which I've found in Rotessa API reference. But I am getting errors in return response instead of JSON string. It would be very helpful if I get help on this. Thanks

curl command:

```
 curl -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H "Authorization: Token 
 token=\"<api_key>\"" -d '{"custom_identifier": "test api", "email": 
 "test@rotessa.com", "name": "Mike Smith", "bank_name": "Scotiabank", 
 "transit_number": "11111", "institution_number": "111", "account_number": 
 "11111111", "address": { "address_1": "123 Main Street", "address_2": "Unit 
 4", "city": "Toronto", "province_code": "ON", "postal_code": "M1B 0B7" }}' 
 <rotessa_endpoint>/customers.json
```

and converted php code:

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.rotessa.com/v1/customers.json");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "{\"custom_identifier\": \"test api\", 
                                   \"email\": \"test@rotessa.com\", 
                                   \"name\": \"Mike Smith\", 
                                   \"bank_name\": \"Scotiabank\", 
                                   \"transit_number\": \"11111\", 
                                   \"institution_number\": \"111\", 
                                   \"account_number\": \"11111111\", 
                                   \"address\": { \"address_1\": \"123 Main
                                                                   Street\", 
                                                  \"address_2\": \"Unit 4\", 
                                                  \"city\": \"Toronto\", 
                                                  \"province_code\": \"ON\", 
                                                  \"postal_code\": \"M1B 
                                                               0B7\" }}");

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

    $headers = array();
    $headers[] = "Content-Type: application/json";
    $headers[] = "Authorization: Token token=\"<api_key>\"";
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
    }


    curl_close ($ch);

    echo $result;
```

it gives the following error:

```
    {"errors":[{"error_code":"unauthorized","error_message":"Not Found."}]}
```

To resolve further confusion I used real api_key in my testing. Just didn't post it here.

Answer (score 1):

Above you have endpoint URL `/customers.json`,
below you have `/customers`.

Comment: Yes, i've noticed and changed accordingly but still getting the same error. Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

Normally the APIs need an API key and should be sent by curl.

```
curl "<rotessa_endpoint>/customers.json" -H "Authorization: Token token=\"<api_key>\""
```

Instead of `<api_key>` should enter your API key.

[rotessa API KEY](https://docs.rotessa.com/#generate-an-api-key)

Comment: @DanFromGermany I don't think so. I thinks in the first he puts just `"<api_key>` instead on real key and in second version ` Token token=\"<token>\""` the same history.

Comment: I think he removed the keys so he does not expose them publicly on the internet.

Comment: Yes, I did enter the API key. without the key, it won't make any sense. As Dan said I just took it off before posting here. But still getting the same error. Thanks for your input.

Comment: @user9310297 Great, is your problem solved or not yet?

Comment: @malus jan No not yet :(

Comment: @user9310297 try this code: `$data = "{'custom_identifier': 'test api','email': 'test@rotessa.com','name': 'Mike Smith','bank_name': 'Scotiabank','transit_number': '11111','institution_number': '111','account_number': '11111111','address': { 'address_1': '123 Main Street','address_2': 'Unit 4','city': 'Toronto','province_code': 'ON','postal_code': 'M1B0B7' }}";
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);`

Comment: @Malus Jan I'll try it and will give you update how it goes...Thanks

Comment: Hi tried with the code you suggested but still it returns NULL.

Comment: Thanks for your input and taking time to look in to it. In fact I tried to encode it too but still same result. I also send request in Postman but same result. I guess there is some problem with endpoint in Rotessa.
Actually, I am developing a loan application when customer get approved the payment will be automatically generated with Rotessa.

Comment: @user9310297 Where can get API key. I need one to test.

Comment: @Malus Jan thanks dear, I would love to give you the API key but guess it's going to breach the agreement with Rotessa. I hope you understand.

Comment: @user9310297 I understand. So can you tell me where can I get one? I created an account but there is not any API KEY

Comment: @Malus Jan Thanks again for your effort. You need to create a sandbox account to try their test environment. But you need to complete the registration with your company information and once they approve and verify your account you'll get API Keys under Admin menu. 
As far I see they don't have many details OR any library for API. Even no Github repository too. Didn't find anyone used their API before in Google.